# BitBucket Server - [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I'm hosting a BitBucket server on my own Windows server and I'm currently playing around with creating repositories and configure them.
But I ran into a problem when I tried to push something to the new repo.

I get the error:

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
 error: failed to push some refs to '<MY_URL>'
```

After some investigation I found out, that the pre-receive hook-files in the repository didn't really work with their default settings.
I commented out the content of this file and tried again but got the same error. Only when I deleted the file and its folder (pre-receive.d) I could push to the repository.

I googled for some hours but haven't found anything that works. I don't believe, that Atlassian set these up, so they wouldn't work on default but if that should be the case I'd need some content I can put in there which works.

The Problem now is, that I can work with these repositories but everytime I create a new one, I have to delete this pre-receive hook-file and I don't think that this is how you should do it.

So my Question now is, where do I have to change something, so these hooks work on default and I can push directly after creating a repository.

Answer (score -3):

Try

1. git reset --hard
2. git pull
3. git push -u origin branch_name